# Artisan server for LAN

Tags: laravel, server, laravel-artisan

I want to make LAN server with artisan server.
How can I run command like this

```
php artisan serve –-host=192.168.2.20 --port=8000
```

I tried but I am getting 'Too many arguments.' error

I know I can do this by virtual host. Just wanted to know how to do with artisan server.

Comment: maybe you should add second '-' for host parameter "--host"

Comment: ohh Its just typo mistake I have edited this, but unfortunately its not working.

Comment: hm in your example dash looks like wrong 
try to copy `php artisan serve --host=192.168.2.20 --port=8000` and run in your console

Comment: @Neha are you seeing `Laravel development server started on http://192.168.2.20:8000/` with the corrected `--` or is it still giving you the error? Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I am using laravel 5.1 , and I getting the error after corrected double dash ( -- )

Comment: `php artisan serve --host 192.168.2.20 --port 8000`

Comment: Thanks @Sid its working

Comment: no problem at all :)

Answer (score 26):

Try copying this:

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.1.1 --port=8000
```

Answer (score 19):

easiest way without knowing your lan IP:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Or as @Gjaa pointed out:

```
php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

I am not a networks expert but I know that 0.0.0.0 will be redirected to your local IP address. and :8000 is the port number.
I use this on mac & Linux and it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

php artisan serve --host 192.168.2.20 --port 8000